# GetModuleFileNameW returns Null on current module

Tags: c, windows

I'm trying to get the path of my currently running executable like so:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    LPWSTR current_filepath = (LPWSTR)malloc(MAX_PATH * sizeof(LPWSTR));
    DWORD path_size = 0;
    DWORD buffer_size = GetModuleFileNameW(0, current_filepath, path_size);
    if (!buffer_size)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        perror("Error: ");
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"%ls \n", current_filepath);
    }
}
```

But when I run the application with a breakpoint on the if I can see that the buffer_size is 0 and the current_filepath is not filled with the path it should be.

I'm not sure on what I did wrong so if anyone has a pointer in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pretty unclear how you got this to compile.  Start with WCHAR current_filepath[MAX_PATH];  And yes, you do get 0 when you say that the buffer size is 0.

Comment: @HansPassant I have changed the code to how I think I should've done it, it compiles on GCC with no warnings. Is there something simple I'm missing?

Comment: *"And yes, you do get 0 when you say that the buffer size is 0."*

Comment: Thank you, TIL I'm terrible at reading.

Comment: `LPWSTR` is a pointer type, so `sizeof(LPWSTR)` is either 4 or 8. You need `sizeof(WCHAR)`, which is 2. I'd start with a stack-allocated buffer, e.g. `WCHAR stack_filepath[MAX_PATH]`, `DWORD path_size = MAX_PATH`, and `LPWSTR current_filepath = stack_filepath`. If it turns out you need more than `MAX_PATH` (i.e. it fails and `GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`), then allocate a bigger buffer. If `current_filepath != stack_filepath`, first `free(current_path)`, and then double the size, i.e. `path_size *= 2` and `current_filepath = malloc(path_size * sizeof(WCHAR))`.

Comment: As noted in the docs, failure is indicate by returning either 0 or the input `path_size`. A successful return value will be greater than 0 and less than `path_size`.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to get the path of my currently running executable like so:

Getting the file path to the currently running EXE basically involves passing `NULL` or `nullptr` to `GetModuleFileName`.

Here's what you really want:

```
LPCWSTR GetPathToRunningExe()
{
    wchar_t szPath[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    DWORD dwSize = GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, szPath, ARRAYSIZE(szPath));
    wchar_t* result = NULL;

    if (dwSize > 0)
    {
        size_t count = wcslen(szPath) + 1;
        result = (wchar_t*)malloc(count * sizeof(szPath[0]));
        wcscpy_s(result, count, szPath);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It's not this simple. Don't assume that `MAX_PATH` is enough. The system supports running an executable from an arbitrary path depth, with a path length up to 32767 characters. You need a loop to retry. If the `dwSize` return value is exactly the current buffer size and `GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`, then you have to allocate a larger buffer and retry. Doubling the current size seems reasonable. You can start with a stack allocated buffer, but for the dynamic buffer switch to the heap via `malloc`.